# Can smooch allow for own apps on Twitter, Facebook etc.

Tags: smooch

We have out own registered apps on twitter, facebook etc. and we have collected a lot of data using these apps. Now if we want to start using Smooch the userId especially on facebook would be lost since it would be our app specific.

Comment: The Smooch REST API allows you to specify a Facebook app when integrating a page, see https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#facebook-messenger.

Comment: Do i need to share the Facebook Secret and other details of my apps with Smooch?

Comment: In order to integrate via the API you need to provide a Facebook app ID and secret, as well as a page access token for the Facebook page.